# Visual Studio 2012 searching for nuget packages fails -- specifically for ninject

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ninject

Does anyone know why it is that when I search using Visual Studio 2012 for the Ninject mvc package it always fails and actually returns a bad result? (see image)
[image: NuGet search fails]

Is Ninject mvc still available?  I can find other packages web essentials, etc.
I can search the nuget.org website and find the ninject package : 
http://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.MVC3/3.0.0.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're searching for `Extensions and Updates`. You should be searching for packages. Right-click the `References` folder under your project in `Solution Explorer` and select `Manage NuGet Packages`. Then search in there.